# Windows 11: Why do drive speeds randomly fluctuate?

Tags: ssd, windows-11

I have a 500MB/s SSD, which is my computer's internal C:\ drive. I noticed that the read/write speeds randomly fluctuate, for example at one point it's at 100% usage while reading at the same speed as it's *going to be reading* in the next few seconds. I know that was terribly confusing, so take a look at the picture below. Also note that the amount of power supplied to the drive always remains the same 24/7 (I mean that the laptop is always plugged in and there's no significant load on any other components). Is this some sort of driver issue? Or is it just one of Windows' 30 year old unexplained mysteries?

[image: Fluctuation Chart - Task Manager]

This is not really an issue for me, I'm just curious why this is happening.

Comment: Have you installed all released updates to Windows 11.  There is a known issue with SSDs that could be at fault.

Comment: Yes I have. Fully updated. Also let me edit the question to state that this is not really an issue for me, I'm just curious why this is happening.

Comment: It could very well be that there are other processes running which happened to need something read from the disk at the same time while your copy was running. An OS being able to do several things at once isn't exactly a mystery – "multi-tasking" was kind of a _selling point_ those 30 years ago. Click the "Open Resource Monitor" link, then wait a bit until this happens again; what processes does the Resource Monitor show as performing I/O?

Comment: Only the Oracle VM process (NOT THE MANAGER, THE ACTUAL VM) is running. I also notice that my disk is NTFS and "ntoskrnl.exe" needs access to disk once in a while. ?

Answer (score 0):

This is *probably* the effects of thermal throttling on the disk in live action. You see, I came up with this question on a gaming laptop. That means there's a CPU overclocked to 4.5GHz and a dedicated GPU constantly chugging at least 20W, which produces an amount of heat comparable to my dad's mini space heater.

That heat probably got spread out (thanks to thermal dissipation) and reached the SSD's microcontroller or flash chips. They have temperature sensors in them which slow or even shut down the disk if it gets hot enough, to prevent overheating and fires etc.

My conclusion is that these reduced speeds are a safety feature. Better have slightly slower R/W speeds than have my house burn down